# Apache Redirect Rule Always fires on every request

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

So the following rewrite rules always seem to fire.  This has the effect of hiding another domain that I am hosting on the server?

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong and it is time to call in the experts:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^danielhonig.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.danielhonig.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.danielhonig.com/gravl
Options None
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the rewrite rules inside your `<VirtualHost>` directive, then it will not affect your other domain.

Comment: Tried putting them in location tags...This caused the site to redirect to the other domain all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `%{SERVER_NAME}` instead of `%{HTTP_HOST}`? I've found `%{SERVER_NAME}` plays nice with sub domains too.